# How to execute this SQL query using ADO.NET?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ado.net

Given this EXACT ad-hoc query:

```
DECLARE @list AS TABLE (Name VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @list(Name)
VALUES ('Otter', 'Lebron', 'Aaron', 'Brock')

SELECT *
FROM Users
WHERE FirstName in (SELECT Name from @list)
```

How can this be done using C# ADO.NET with a SqlParameter?

Comment: Did you really need to make the table variable for the single value, or is this an over-simplification? In other words, why 2+ statements instead of 1? What would be the parameter?

Comment: The example was over simplified, edited to make more sense.

Comment: What kind of parameter would this list be from the ADO.NET side, a DataTable or a string?

Comment: Well I'm going to have the list represented as a string array... I can convert it to whatever type is necessary, I just don't know what that type should be.  I tried both DataTable and List<SqlDataRecord> with no luck.

Comment: Pose your question with your constraints UP FRONT. Don't allow people to compose **answers for you, waste their time**, and throw constraints at them. Very discourteous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using a modification of your orginal SQL for sample purposes.

```
DECLARE @list AS TABLE (Name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO @list(Name)
VALUES ('PROCEDURE'), 
        ('FUNCTION');

SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE in (SELECT Name from @list)
```

**You can use a Table-Valued Parameter**

Here's a modified example taken from [Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server 2008 (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)

```
        using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
        {

            var tableParam = new DataTable("names");
            tableParam.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            tableParam.Rows.Add(new object[] { "PROCEDURE" });
            tableParam.Rows.Add(new object[] { "FUNCTION')" });

            var sql = @"DECLARE @list AS TABLE (Name VARCHAR(20))
                       INSERT INTO @list(Name)
                       SELECT Name from @Names;

                       SELECT *
                       FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
                       WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE in (SELECT Name from @list)";

            var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
            var tvpParam = sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Names", tableParam);
            tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            tvpParam.TypeName = "dbo.Names";

            cnn.Open();
            using(SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader() )
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                    Console.WriteLine(rdr["SPECIFIC_NAME"]);                    

            }



        }
```

But you need to define the type dbo.Names before it can work

Here's the type creation SQL

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.Names AS TABLE 
( Name VARCHAR(Max));
```

**Another option is to use an [XML Parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34e4kcbw.aspx)**

```
 using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
{



    var sql = @"DECLARE @list AS TABLE (Name VARCHAR(20))
                INSERT INTO @list(Name)
                SELECT t.name.value('.', 'varchar(MAX)')
                FROM   @Names.nodes('/Names/Name') as T(Name);

                SELECT *
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
                WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE in (SELECT Name from @list)";

    var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);

    var s = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes("<Names><Name>PROCEDURE</Name><Name>FUNCTION</Name></Names>"));


    var xmlParam = new SqlXml(s);

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Names", xmlParam);


    cnn.Open();
    using(SqlDataReader rdr = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader() )
    {
        while (rdr.Read())
            Console.WriteLine(rdr["SPECIFIC_NAME"]);                    

    }



}
```

Comment: I am hoping to achieve this without creating a type because my DBA's are resisting this.

Comment: <sigh> Don't know why your DBA would resist that. Its pretty low impact. I guess you other option is XML. updating the answer