# can I combine a select count(*) and sum(column) in a single select?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I am presently pulling two long values from my database with two selects:

```
// We need the number of users and the total bandwidth
long numUsers, totalBandwidth;
using (IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from [User] where [User].CompanyId = @CompanyId";
    DbUtilities.AddParam(cmd, "@CompanyId", id);
    numUsers = (long)(decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
using (IDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select sum(BandwidthThisMonth) from [User] where [User].CompanyId = @CompanyId";
    DbUtilities.AddParam(cmd, "@CompanyId", id);
    totalBandwidth = (long)(decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

I think logically this can be a single select that returns two numbers. But everything I've tried has given me errors. Can this be done?

Comment: `select count(*) as count_all, sum(BandwidthThisMonth) as sum_BandwidthThisMonth from ....` but you'll get two columns back instead of one scalar.  [so you'll need to handle that...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8159184/623952)

Comment: Please make that an answer and I'll select it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  count(*) as count_all, 
        sum(BandwidthThisMonth) as sum_BandwidthThisMonth 

from    [User] 

where   [User].CompanyId = @CompanyId
```

but you'll get two columns back instead of one scalar.  [so you'll need to handle that...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8159184/623952)

Answer (score 0):

If you want them in the same column, you can use a union. This scans the table 2 times, so not as efficient.

```
select  "count" as key
, count(*) as value
from    [User] 
where   [User].CompanyId = @CompanyId
union all
select  "sum_BandwidthThisMonth" key
, sum(BandwidthThisMonth) as value 
from    [User] 
where   [User].CompanyId = @CompanyId
```

Use union all if you don't want a sort. Union does a sort. Not a big deal with 2 rows, but...